# Probability of an event occuring twice

Tags: probability, statistics

You have to shake hands of everyone in a crowd. Every time you shake a hand, you have a probability of catching a disease and or winning \$1,000.

You could catch multiple diseases at once, or catch a diseases and win \$1,000 at the same time. You could also catch the same disease or win \$1,000   multiple times during your hand shake run. I would call this independant events.

Let $B$ be the event that you win \$1,000 . 
Let $M, I, G, V, O, L, S, J, C, Z$ be the list of diseases that you can catch when you shake a hand.

Here is the probability of each event occuring when shaking a hand :

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{c|c}
Event & Probability \\ 
B     & 1/1667462   \\
M     & 1/404085    \\
G     & 1/574858    \\
I     & 1/606127    \\
O     & 1/820740    \\
V     & 1/862287    \\
S     & 1/1111641   \\
L     & 1/1231110   \\
J     & 1/1501674   \\
C     & 1/2252512   \\
Z     & 1/5857437   \\ 
\end{array}
\right]
$$

Scenario we are looking at :

M. NotClean pretends he won \$2,000 and didn't catch a disease in his run. He shook $127,926$ hands.

That seems unbelievable to me, but I'm struggling answering those questions I have :

**What is the probability that somebody win \$1,000 by shaking $127,926$ hands ?**

**What is the probability that somebody win \$2,000 by shaking $127,926$ hands ?**

**What is the probability that somebody catches no disease by shaking $127,926$ hands ?**

**What is the probability that somebody catches no disease and wins \$1,000 by shaking $127,926$ hands ?**

**What is the probability that somebody catches no disease and wins \$2,000 by shaking $127,926$ hands ?**

This is not a homework, it is hobby related.

Comment: Too many questions and not enough (no) effort.

Comment: @calculus You can contribute by showing me how to get one of them answered and I can work out the rest.

Comment: answer for 1st one : $ \binom{127926}{1}\cdot P(B).[1-P(B)]^{127925}$